# Kendo UI Treeview: suppress expand/collapse and select child nodes on dblclick

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo UI Treeview with checkboxes set up on my page

I want to suppress expand/collapse of child nodes on double click and check child nodes on dblclick

i have tried

```
 $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({ }).on('dblclick', '.k-in', function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            alert('dblclick');
        }).data("kendoTreeView")
```

prevent default does not seem to supress expand and collapse

Answer (score 3):

try this:
`$("#treeview").unbind("dblclick");`

Answer (score 2):

Hi you don't want to expand or collapse on double click event then do it like this...

```
 $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({ }).on('dblclick', '.k-in', function (event) { 
     alert('dblclick');
     return false;
}).data("kendoTreeView")
```

just add one more line return false in your code.
this is working fine..

see the working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/GaFd6/37/
in above example if you will double click on tree then node will not  expand.

Thanks

Comment: i have attached an example link in  my answer please check

Comment: Please remove the alert box from the sample it does not work , the alert box supress the event but the function does not

Comment: i removed the alert and still its working...http://jsfiddle.net/GaFd6/38/ and i have tested this in chrome,IE11 and mozilla in both browsers its working as expected...thanks

Comment: Somehow it does not seem to work in my code , i have hooked up check boxes , select and change events , tried commenting everything still does not work , thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of expand on dblclick:

```
$('#treeview').off('dblclick', '.k-in:not(.k-state-disabled)');
```

To get rid of expand on dblclick & add something else instead:

```
$('#treeview').off('dblclick', '.k-in:not(.k-state-disabled)')
    .on('dblclick', '.k-in:not(.k-state-disabled)', function(evt) {
        // your stuff
    });
```